# How to replace String in a textfile and save it to a new file?

Tags: python

I have a code where I can write in to the same file but I want to write in to a new file so the first file should be constant.

```
from pathlib import Path
filename ="input.txt"
outputfile = "output.txt"
text_to_search_old1 = input("const String roomname_short:(old): ");
replacement_text_new1 = input("const String roomname_short:(new): ");
text_to_search_old2 = input("const String roomname_short:(old): ");
replacement_text_new2 = input("const String roomname_short:(new): ");

path = Path(filename)
path2 = Path(outputfile)
text = path.read_text()
text2 = path.read.text()
text = text.replace(text_to_search_old1, replacement_text_new1)
text = text.replace(text_to_search_old2, replacement_text_new2)
path.write_text(text2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `copyfile` method from the `shutil` module:

```
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copyfile

filename = "input.txt"
outputfile = "output.txt"

copyfile(filename, outputfile)

text_to_search_old1 = input("const String roomname_short:(old): ");
replacement_text_new1 = input("const String roomname_short:(new): ");
text_to_search_old2 = input("const String roomname_short:(old): ");
replacement_text_new2 = input("const String roomname_short:(new): ");

path = Path(outputfile)
text = path.read_text()
text = text.replace(text_to_search_old1, replacement_text_new1)
text = text.replace(text_to_search_old2, replacement_text_new2)
path.write_text(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `shutil` to copy a file to the target location. You can do the modification on the copied file then. Detailed documentation on `shutil` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html).

```
import shutil

original = r'original path where the file is currently stored\file name.file extension'
target = r'target path where the file will be copied\file name.file extension'

shutil.copyfile(original, target)
```

Comment: Thanks, to you also